# Mac OS Python Install Messed Up

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pip

I am trying to start on a python project, and I needed some data science libraries, and was directed to install Anaconda. 
After installing it I realized I didnt want it, so I tried uninstalling it.

Now im trying to install a package with pip, but I guess pip is not installed, or my paths are all out of wack now, and im confused because python is in multiple places.

In `/Library/Python` I have a 2.6 and 2.7 folder, both containing only Extras.pth and README

In `/usr/local/bin` I have `python2 python2-config python2.7 python2.7-config  pythonw2 pythonw2.7`
This is apparently the Pipenv Environment? When i create a new project in PyCharm `/usr/local/bin/python2.7` is the directory it wants to use.

And theres python in

```
/usr/local/opt/python
/usr/loca/opt/python2
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13_1/
```

My issue is when I want to install anything with pip i get

```
-bash: pip: command not found
```

When i run `sudo easy_install pip` i get

```
Searching for pip
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'pip' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or download links found for pip
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pip')
```

Running `which python` gives `/usr/bin/python`

So now im confused on which python directory is which and how i can get pip to work again.

The only place i know that pip exists and works in my Homebrew install of `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13_1/bin/pip`

Can any one help me sort this out?

Comment: Have you tried the install directions for pip at https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Comment: First of all, run `brew doctor` and see if it outputs something meaningful.

Answer (score 3):

This might take some iterations to answer, but I'll try.
Unfortunately my reputation doesn't allow comments yet :(

First, I would check PATH environment variable:

```
$ echo $PATH
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

In my case, the first thing in PATH is python 3.6 from python.org, then other standard paths.

I also have Extras.pth and README in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` along with some other packages installed.

The python at /usr/bin/python should be the default python, installed with OSX.

Any other python you installed is going to be in /usr/local/bin. You can figure out what those are by doing a full listing to see where the symlinks point

```
$ ls -al /usr/local/bin/python*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 username  wheel  38 Jun 21 10:21 /usr/local/bin/python -> ../Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/bin/python
lrwxr-xr-x  1 username  wheel  45 Jun 21 10:21 /usr/local/bin/python-config -> ../Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/bin/python-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 username  wheel  39 Jun 21 10:21 /usr/local/bin/python2 -> ../Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/bin/python2
lrwxr-xr-x  1 username  wheel  46 Jun 21 10:21 /usr/local/bin/python2-config -> ../Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/bin/python2-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 username  wheel  41 Jun 21 10:21 /usr/local/bin/python2.7 -> ../Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/bin/python2.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 username  wheel  48 Jun 21 10:21 /usr/local/bin/python2.7-config -> ../Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/bin/python2.7-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  69 Aug  6 22:31 /usr/local/bin/python3 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  76 Aug  6 22:31 /usr/local/bin/python3-config -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  71 Aug  6 22:31 /usr/local/bin/python3.6 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  78 Aug  6 22:31 /usr/local/bin/python3.6-config -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  72 Aug  6 22:31 /usr/local/bin/python3.6m -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6m
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  79 Aug  6 22:31 /usr/local/bin/python3.6m-config -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6m-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 username  wheel  39 Jun 21 10:21 /usr/local/bin/pythonw -> ../Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/bin/pythonw
lrwxr-xr-x  1 username  wheel  40 Jun 21 10:21 /usr/local/bin/pythonw2 -> ../Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/bin/pythonw2
lrwxr-xr-x  1 username  wheel  42 Jun 21 10:21 /usr/local/bin/pythonw2.7 -> ../Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/bin/pythonw2.7
```

In my case, I have installed Homebrew python 2.7.15 (anything starting with `Cellar`) and Python.org 3.6 (in `/Library/Frameworks`)

So... back to what you are trying to do.

If you want to run Homebrew python type `python2` at the prompt.
If you want to run OSX python, type `python`.

If you want to run Homebrew as the default, just by typing `python`, you would have to add symlinks in /usr/local/bin similar to the first 2 lines in my listing, so that they are looked up in your path before /usr/bin (you would override the python command).

I'm not sure why your easy_install is failing, but `which easy_install` will probably tell you that this points only at the OSX python install version of easy_install also.

I hope that helps? Unfortunately I cannot replicate your error as I have pip installed already.